# Print a value in php file using html [beginner]

Tags: php, html

**Hello i have a php file called a.php that includes a specific value
example : $a = 0;
i just want to print this value (a) in a html file called b.html is that possible ?** thanks

Comment: What did you try already? Did you Google 'mixing PHP and HTML'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you have to open php tag, include php file, echo variable and close php tag
For example:

`<p><?php include('a.php'); echo $a; ?></p>`

Answer (score 0):

This will work..

```
<?php
ob_start();
$a = 1;
echo $a;    // echo $a value
file_put_contents('b.html', ob_get_contents()); // save the output to b.html
?>
```

However, if you already have other content in the existing page all of them will be there in the html file. Therefore you can POST the variable $a to a separate php file as follows..

```
<?php
ob_start();
$a = $_POST["aVar"];
echo $a;
file_put_contents('b.html', ob_get_contents());
?>
```